# Apache virtual subdomains

Tags: apache-http-server, xampp

I'm trying to create virtual subdomains but apache fails to start after I edit the httpd-vhosts.conf and there are no errors in the error log.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  ServerAlias *.localhost
  UseCanonicalName Off    
  VirtualDocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/%1
</VirtualHost>
```

Note:
I'm running apache via xampp on windows.

Answer (score 0):

It' my way to create virtual hosts in linux:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
  DocumentRoot /var/webapps/testphp
  ServerName testphp.home.lan
</VirtualHost>
```

You may use it (replace DocumentRoot and ServerName) and add

```
127.0.0.1 testphp.home.lan
```

in you /etc/hosts (or windows-os c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts)
And check is there "error-switcher" in main apache config. May be your error log is switched-off.

Comment: I'm running on windows, and this is not what I'm searching for... read the question... :\

Comment: ok, replace like this "DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/testphp"